# Nginx - creating a subdomain linking to another (local) website

Tags: dns, ip, nginx, webserver, domain

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 based DigitalOcean VPS with a pure Nginx (I manage DNSs via DigitalOcean's DNS managing tool). In my Nginx environment I have 2 sites under `/var/www/html/`. One is `example.com` (HTTPS) and the other is a domainless site with a directory named `test` (HTTP).

How to create a subdomain for **example.com** that will lead into **test**? (`test.example.com`)?

---

#### 1) My [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d857efe569cb6764f82e19c468b514e5).

#### 2) My `example.com` site-conf:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 80; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot
}
```

#### 3) My `test` site-conf:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/test;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```

### Update:

- I've yet to change anything in my VPS hosting provider's DNS management tool.
- I want everyone in the world to be able to access the `test` site via the subdomain.

Comment: You'll have to adjust the DNS management tool to adjust the DNS to match.  That is its own question and set of tasks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are needed in any Nginx and DNS environment to properly make a new subdomain with a different document root:

1. An addtional `server { }` block to handle it (besides the one you already have in item #3).
2. A DNS record to point the other subdomain to the proper webserver.

Based on the configuration provided, you need to do 2 things:

1. Your `test.example.com` site configuration is missing a `server_name test.example.com;` directive. Add one and restart your `nginx` process.
2. Set a `test.example.com` DNS record in the DNS for your main domain (likely, from your cloud's DNS management tool).

<sub>Always tell NGINX what sites to process with what server blocks. As the package maintainer for `nginx` in Ubuntu, I am familiar with most of the user-level pitfalls people encounter, such as this.</sub>

---

You gave us this:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/test;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```

So *literally* just add right before your `root` line, this line:

```
server_name test.example.com;
```

... and you get this configuration file:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/test;
    server_name test.example.com;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```